# Increase in memory uses on master node while using MPISend and MPIReceive

Tags: mpi

I am writing a program using MPI where master allocates task to slave nodes. Every slave node executes the task locally and sends the result (int array of size 100000) to the master node.

Though I am getting correct results memory uses are not linear. I found that master node takes up N*m memory where N is the number of nodes and m is the memory typically used by slave node.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening and is there any solution to reduce memory uses on master node.

Here is the sample code in which slave nodes sends some data/results to master node and I want to know why memory uses at master node is N*m. I checked memory uses using Linux command top.

```
#include<iostream>  
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argv, char *argp[256])
{
    int rank,size,master_rank=0,i=0;
    int jc=0,jpt,jobsperthread=0,exjpt=0;;
    int ii=0,index=0,remaining=0,tobesent=0,tobereceived=0;
    int totsendreceivesize=100000,k=0;
    int innodes=11;
    MPI_Status status;
    int *arr_anti_net=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(totsendreceivesize+100));
    MPI_Init (&argv, &argp);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    for(i=0;i<totsendreceivesize;i++)
       arr_anti_net[i]=i
    if(rank!=master_rank)
    {
       remaining=totsendreceivesize;
       tobesent=256;
       k=0;
       while(remaining!=0)
       {
        if(remaining<256)
            tobesent=remaining;
        MPI_Send(&arr_anti_net[k],tobesent,MPI_INT,0,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        k+=tobesent;
        remaining-=tobesent;
       }
    }
    else
    {
       ii=0;
       index=0;
       for(ii=1;ii<size;ii++)
       {
           jc=0;
           jpt=0;
           jobsperthread=innodes/size;
           jpt=innodes/size;
           exjpt=0;
           if(innodes%size!=0)
           {
            if(ii<innodes%size)
            {
                jobsperthread+=1;
                exjpt=ii;
            }
            else
                exjpt=innodes%size;
           }
           remaining=256;//totsendreceivesize;
           tobereceived=256;
           k=0;
           while(remaining!=0)
           {
            if(remaining<256)
                tobereceived=remaining;
            MPI_Recv(& arr_anti_net[k],tobereceived,MPI_INT,ii,11,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
            k+=tobereceived;
            remaining-=tobereceived;
           }
       }
      }
   MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Let me try to understand what you are saying: There are `N` nodes sending their result of size `m` to the master and you wonder why the master requires `N*m` memory? You will need to supply some code and be more specific of the structure of the result to receive an appropriate answer.

Comment: Your program does send a big piece of data as 391 small messages (why?) from each slave, but receives only one small message from each slave on the master. I would not even care about memory usage at that point: 1) Understand how to correctly use point to point communication 2) Use the appropriate collective communication (e.g. `MPI_Gather` instead 3) Care about memory - in that order.